# Carry function input to source()

Tags: r, function, lapply

I want to run a function on multiple datasets with `lapply`. I wrote a function which accesses different R scripts via `source()`, however the objects created in the function are not carried over to the "source code". Something like:

```
one = seq(1:10000)
two = seq(10001:20000)
three = seq(20001:30000)

ott = list(one, two, three)

test = function(x){

    yt = diff(log(x), 10)

    source("C:/blabla")

    return("something calculated in source")
 }

lapply(ott, test)
```

when `source()` is something like

```
result=yt+1
```

the corresponding error message is:

> could not find object yt in source()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions create their own environment and variables created in the function only exist in this environment. By default, `source` executes in the the global environment and so cannot find objects created in the function.

You can tell `source` to run in the environment created by the functionby setting the local argument to TRUE.

```
test = function(x){

  yt = diff(log(x), 10)

  this <- source("./temp.R", local=TRUE)

  return("something calculated in source")
}
```

Then the `lapply` returns

```
lapply(ott, test)
[[1]]
[1] "something calculated in source"

[[2]]
[1] "something calculated in source"

[[3]]
[1] "something calculated in source"
```